# phpseclib get is changing my file name and puts special characters

Tags: php, sftp, phpseclib

Im downloading files from sftp using phpseclib get method, but it adds special characters to the file name. Ive notice it only does that if the file has a long name. Ive tried removing '_' but is still puts those characters.

```
$sftp->get($order, 'Modules\*' . $order))
```

original name:

```
Master-124251-SALES_​CMPLT​_NOTIFICATION-01102019-102045.csv
```

output:

```
Master-124251-SALES_â€‹CMPLTâ€‹_NOTIFICATION-01102019-102045.csv
```

Any solutions for this? thanks guys

Comment: What is the purpose of `*`? Where do you get `$order` value from? What does `strlen($order)` return for that specific file name from your question?

Comment: $order comes from a foreach with all the files inside the folder. The * is just to replace the path because it was too long to post here. the strlen() puts out 61

Comment: `$sftp->get()` returns the contents of said file - it doesn't return the name of said file. It's possible the contents of said file include the name but that's another matter entirely.

Comment: @neubert Not when the second argument is set: *"If $local_file is defined, returns true or false depending on the success of the operation"*

Comment: @neubert im returning the file not the contente with $sftp->get($order, 'Modules\*' . $order)

Comment: Good point - I didn't see that. That said...  all phpseclib really does is just pass that parameter, without alteration, to `fopen()`: https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/2.0.21/phpseclib/Net/SFTP.php#L2188 Given that this seems more like a PHP issue idk. What happens if you do `$fp = fopen('Modules\*' . $order, 'wb'); fputs($fp, '...'); fclose($fp);`?

Comment: its the same, it inserts special characters into the file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i figure it out with the reminder of one person. 
I just added this to my server config

```
<add key="AddDefaultCharset" value="utf8_general_ci"/>
```

And it works just fine. Hope it helps anyone.